# Do the Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P have the same camera?

Tags: camera

The Nexus 6P has an excellent camera.

Is the camera hardware and photo-processing on the Nexus 5X exactly the same as the 6P?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Nexus 6P and 5X share the same 12MP camera with a Sony-made sensor according to [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p-vs-nexus-5x-camera/) article on XDA, which is generally considered a reliable source.